# Rendering pages in mvc3 from xml

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I want some static pages of application to be rendered from XML i.e. i am planning to have a base page and xml containing structure of the page and xslt which will be transforming this xml to html and at runtime i will be rendering this html to my view and displaying this view 
 Is there any way/ example for doing the same. Please help
 Here is the sample xml

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
     <head>
   <title>Create</title>
  <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js" type="text/javascript" />
        <link href="/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
      <link href="/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript" />
        <script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript" />
      <script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js" type="text/javascript" />
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js" type="text/javascript" />

     </head>
     <body>
 <div id="menucontainer">
  <ul id="menu">
    <li>
      <a href="/">Rutu</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/Employee">Employee</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<h2>Create</h2>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript" />
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js" type="text/javascript" />
<form action="/Employee/Create" method="post">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>EmployeeDetailsModel</legend>
    <div class="editor-label">
      <label for="EmpName">EmpName</label>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
      <input class="text-box single-line" id="EmpName" name="EmpName" type="text" value="" />
      <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="EmpName" data-valmsg-replace="true" />
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
      <label for="DeptId">DeptId</label>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
      <input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field  DeptId must be a number." data-val-required="The DeptId field is required." id="DeptId" name="DeptId" type="text" value="" />
      <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="DeptId" data-valmsg- replace="true" />
    </div>
    <p>
      <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
   </fieldset>
</form>
<div>
  <a href="/Employee">Back to List</a>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by XML containing the structure of the page? Can you show an example of how such XML might look like? And the expected output?

Comment: Hi Darin attaching sample xml file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [good blog post here](http://tutorialgenius.blogspot.com/2011/06/c-mvc-3-render-xslt-htmlhelper.html) that describes how to create an HTML Helper to render the XSLT in a view. You just call the helper class from your view passing in the path to the XSLT and the XML.  I have modified this helper so that you can also pass the XSLT and XML as strings to achieve the same results.

Comment: thanks for this link Can you provide me xslt being used in that example and how validation can be done?

Comment: @Rutu - Which example are you referring to? The work I did on this was for a proof of concept to see if it was feasible because we were migrating from ASP.NET Forms based applications that used XSLT extensively to MVC and Razor. We did not move forward with using this approach because we determined that Razor was a better solution than XSLT in an MVC environment.  See my answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9826676/reasons-for-using-xsl-when-razor-templates-exist.

Comment: i am refering http://tutorialgenius.blogspot.in/2011/06/c-mvc-3-render-xslt-htmlhelper.html link i want to use this mechanism for a single page rendering with same model but varying in view by no. of fields supplied in xml

Comment: @Rutu - As I mentioned we dropped this approach for Razor so we did not get into how validation would work. You can use any XSLT and XML example you may have to verify this works. If you are new to XSLT I would recommend going with Razor as it has better integration in MVC, has great support for validation, is easier to learn, and an easier to understand syntax.

Comment: Thanks Now i am also using razor view

Answer (score 0):

MvcContrib project provides an XSLT based view engine http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/releases - I would suggest to check it out.